# Purpose of using provisioning sofware in virtual machine like Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, puppet

I am a very new in web application development.My question is whats the purpose of using provisioning software like Puppet or Chef while using Vagrant as a Virtual machine.

Comment: The purpose is to validate your provisionning method/code before  it will be used in production and to avoid bug/mistakes in the provisionning. (biref answer, google as a lot of detailled links on TDD and CI workflows)

Answer (score 0):

Largely it is about consistency.  Vagrant simply gives you a virtual machine.  Chef/Puppet, allows you to configure that machine in EXACTLY the same way, every time.  So you can do some development, spin up a VM, deploy your code to it, and test.  Once you're done, you can destroy the VM, do some more development, and start again from scratch.  This ensures that things like debugging don't give you a false sense of security.  Since each test session starts with a totally clean environment, you know what you're getting.  Finally, once you finish all that testing, you have a consistent method for deplying to your production environment.  Again, knowing that everything will remain consistent as Chef will do the same thing in production as it did in vagrant.